# Best Practice : Seconds Since datetime when datetime is empty or null

Tags: php, datetime, return-value, return-type

I feel this question is language agnostic, but I will use PHP for my example

```php
abstract class myUserClass {
  private $last_visit = null;

  abstract getLastVisit() ?string;
  abstract secondsSinceLastVisit() int;

}
```

Lets say you have some datetime (like a last_visit) property on an object

`last_visit` = `2020-10-10 09:25:25`

`last_visit` can be a string representation of the datetime OR `null` of user has never visited

And then you have a method like `secondsSinceLastVisit() : int`

And this function returns an `int` representing the number of seconds SINCE `last_visit`

What would be the best practice for returning when `last_visit` is null?

We could:
return `null` which means this is undefined
Return `some_really_large_number` meaning - a long time ago
Something else???

I ran into trouble doing this

```php
if( !$user->secondsSinceLastVisit() )
{
 //user has never visited
}
```

This failed during some unit testing when `secondsSinceLastVisit()` returned zero! `0`

So, I changed by test to `is_null( $user->secondsSinceLastVisit() )` which solves this problem

My question is general in nature - What is a good practice here for the return value of `secondsSinceLastVisit()` when `last_visit` is null?

Comment: Why do poeple think anyone is fooled by "Whats best practice for"

Comment: @RiggsFolly "i before e, except after c". Hm.... does that apply to "e before o, except after p"? Heh.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Nicked

Comment: If I were implementing this, I would return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really 2 good options:

1. Return `null`. `null` is often a stand-in for the absence of a value, so this makes perfect sense here.
2. Throw an Exception

I think either is fine, but which one you choose depends on the answer to the question:

"Is it a bug when somebody calls `secondsSinceLastVisit()` for a user when the user has not visited yet?"

Comment: Thank you - The question "Is it a bug when somebody calls secondsSinceLastVisit() for a user when the user has not visited yet?" really helped.   Which in my case, I would say this is true - Therefore, throw an exception